# As a Ruby/Rails Developer, zsh vs bash? What's the advantage?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, zsh

I've seen a lot of people recommend zsh over bash for ruby development and i'm failing to understand what zsh offers over bash?

The answerable question for this post is:

What benefit, specific to ruby developers, does one see when using zsh instead of bash?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Edit : this applies if you use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

Personally, I'm mainly using it because it displays your current git branch in the command prompt. Therefore, if like me you often have to switch branches, you don't mix code by accident.

Also, one of the nice benefits for me is that I created a fork of `oh-my-zsh` with my custom theme enabled by default, and I can deploy it on whatever machine I need it onto (say, production servers) with just a few commands. This way, I load up all my zsh aliases, my custom theme etc ...

Finally there's a zsh plugin I'm using that is [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting). This highlights commands as you type them, to make it dummy-proof. Green = good existing command, red = you made a typo ... but there's more to it, it's worth a try.

So yeah, git integration and the ability to install my own personal zsh setup on whatever machine within seconds is why I like it.

There's also a railscast talking about oh-my-zsh : http://railscasts.com/episodes/308-oh-my-zsh

Comment: You can do the git stuff in bash too, though, pretty easily. I'm of two minds about zsh; I use it, but it pauses enough to be annoying, and in real life, we grow to rely on our personal environment, and it isn't always possible to port it to arbitrary machines.

Comment: +1 for oh-my-zsh. Biggest factor in making me fall in love with the terminal since vim.

Answer (score 1):

A Ruby developer is unlikely to notice the difference unless they do some sort of shell scripting. The big wins for Zsh are:

- Better autocompletion (IMHO--bash has autocompletion but, somehow, zsh's is just more intuitive, more fluid and generally more mature).
- Additional data structures.
- Additional modules.

Autocompletion is the biggest day to day difference. The rest you will only notice if you write shell scripts.